# Solving Multiple Equations with Many Variables

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Here's a problem I have stumbled upon, which may have a straightforward solution with linear algebra. If so, I cannot see it.

Choose $n > 0 \in \mathbb N$, and consider the sequence of equations:

$$nx_1 + (n-1)y_1 - 1 = 0$$
$$nx_2 + (n-2)y_2 - 1 = 0$$
$$...$$
$$nx_{n-1} + y_{n-1} - 1 = 0$$

Equivalently, consider all equations for $0 < k < n$ such that

$$nx_k + (n-k)y_k - 1 = 0$$

How might I go about determining if these equations have a solution for $x_k, y_k \in \mathbb R$? In particular, I was hoping someone could help me restate the problem using linear algebra.

NOTE

The original formulation required $x_k, y_k \in \mathbb Z$, in which case, the existence of a solution to these equations is true iff $n$ is prime. I've weakened the constraint in the hopes of finding ways to express or understand this problem without the concepts of $gcd$ or the Euclidean Algorithm.

Comment: What relationship do these equations have to each other? Are we solving each one separately?

Comment: I would like to find a more concise way of expressing the solution set of these equations. As you noted in your answer below, the statement that these equations have solutions in $\mathbb Z$ is equivalent to the statement that n is prime. In particular, linear algebra provides methods of reformulating solutions of linear equations, which I have used to good effect for past problems. I was hoping someone could provide an analysis outside the bounds of number theory.

Comment: Can you give an example of a specific system of equations?

Comment: Sure. For any prime, the series of equations above will have a solution. Therefore, expressing when the equations have a solution provides another way to express that n is prime. Choose $n = 5$.

For coefficients $x_i, y_i$, the following equations will all have integer solutions:

$$5x_1 - 4y_1 = 1$$
$$5x_2 - 3y_2 = 1$$
$$5x_3 - 2y_3 = 1$$
$$5x_4 - 1y_4 = 1$$

Answer (score 1):

By Bézout's Theorem, the diophantine equation $$ax + by = 1$$ where $a, b \in \mathbb Z$ has integer solutions for $x$ and $y$ if and only if $hcf(a,b)=1$.

Hence, the equation $$nx_k + (n-k)y_k - 1 = 0$$has solutions if and only if $$hcf(n, n-k) = hcf(n,k)=1$$

In particular, if $n$ is prime, then all of the equations will have solutions.

Comment: Yes, that was how these equations were formulated. n is prime iff this particular sequence of diophantine equations are solvable. I am hoping to find a more consice way to express a solution to these equations, perhaps weakening the constraint to $x_k,y_k \in \mathbb R$, which might provide me with a new way of thinking about primality

Comment: If you weaken the constraint to $x_k,y_k \in \mathbb{R}$, then there are infinitely many solutions regardless of whether or not $n$ is prime.

Answer (score 0):

If $n$ is not prime, then let $d$ be a divisor of $n$ such that $1 < d < n$. Then, $nx_{n-d} + dy_{n-d} = d\left(\tfrac{n}{d}x_{n-d}+y_{n-d}\right)$ is a multiple of $d$, so $nx_{n-d} + dy_{n-d} = 1$ has no solutions.

If $n$ is prime, then $\text{gcd}(k,n) = 1$ for all $1 \le k < n$, and so we can use the Euclidan Algorithm to find a solution $(x_k,y_k)$ for each equation $nx_{n-k} + ky_{n-k} = 1$.

Comment: It's not just divisors for which it fails. For example if $n = 6$, then there are no solutions for $x_4, y_4$

Comment: Each equation has no solution in $\mathbb Z$ when $n$ is not coprime to $n-k$. This means they share a common divisor greater than 1, which is a stronger statement than $n-k$ divides $n$.

Comment: Regardless, there is no solution to the system of equations if $n$ is not prime. Showing that there is no solution to one of the equations is sufficient to make this claim.